# mod_rewrite do not work with jQuery.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using WAMP, jQuery and CodeIgniter. I have done creating .htaccess to remove index.php and it work properly.

But with $.ajax is not work. it has to access with index.php. What am I doing wrong? ?

Here is .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is the caller

```
var url =  base_url + 'spider/ajax_trade_open/';

//var url =  base_url + 'index.php/spider/ajax_trade_open/'; // this work

$.ajax({
  'url': url,
  'type': 'GET',
  'success': function (data) {
    alert('success');
  },
  'error': function (obj, title, ex) {
    alert(title + ': ' + ex);
  }
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: In this rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]` I think you need replace `index.php?/$1` with `index.php/$1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule **before your existing rule**:

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.php/(.+)$ $1?/$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Here is the htaccess after adjusting by your comment. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(index\.php/(.+)$ $1?/$2 [L,NC,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: For which URL it doesn't work and are you getting 404?

Comment: The url is "http://localhost/spider/ajax_trade_open/".

All work fine except calling by $.ajax. It return error state with Not Found description. With index.php it worked.

Thank you very much for your kindly support.

Comment: Sorry for my poor english. It did not work fine for AJAX. To call with $.ajax(), I need set the url with index.php. It make me be wonder, what difference between calling by direct access and GET method of $.ajax().

Comment: Can you test Ajax call in Firebug and tell me what **exact URL is causing 404**

Comment: It's my mistake. I typed your advice with missing a space. Thank you for your kindly advice.